# kexec for fast reboot installed - do one-time-only full reboot

Tags: linux, boot, debian, grub, reboot

I have got `kexec` installed to do quick warm reboots without BIOS POST'ing and GRUB popping up. It will just reinit the kernel and do the bootprocess again.

Sometimes however, I like to do a full reboot, for example to change some BIOS settings or to start a different OS. I do this now by shutting down first.

Is there a command I can do in (Debian) Linux to ignore kexec and just do an oldskool full (warm) reboot including POST?

Needless to say, `$ reboot` is configured to use `kexec`. This all happens automatically when installing `kexec`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Debian provides the script /sbin/coldreboot.

From the man page: "coldreboot  is  a  script  that  forces a cold reboot regardless of whether kexec is enabled or not in /etc/default/kexec."

Comment: This is a nice one. Just as I found out I cannot kexec-less reboot anymore. They should make this default for the desktop GUI reboot option - IMO.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.gentoo-wiki.info/Kexec#Rebooting_the_normal_way) is instruction for Gentoo, but the same idea. Hope it will be useful:

Just stop the kexec daemon before rebooting. `sudo /etc/init.d/kexec stop`

Comment: Thank you. Quite simple, I hadn't found this instruction before. I've edited your answer to include the instruction

Comment: I just found out this doesn't seem to work (anymore) on recent Debian?